# Is there a way to drop packets when listening on internet interface?

Tags: go, networking, packet, sniffing

Let's say an HTTP server is running on port 8080. I want all packets on "eth0" that have destination port 8080 in their TCP header and some other condition is met(for instance URG flag is up) to be dropped before reaching the server (with other words the server should not be able to see these packets). Something like a "firewall".

I need a Go implementation. So far I managed to capture the network traffic on "eth0" and I know how to filter it. Is there any way I can drop the packets that I captured by the following program:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

var (
    device string = "en0"
    snaplen int32 = 65535
    promisc bool = false
    err error
    timeout time.Duration = -1 * time.Second
    handle *pcap.Handle
)

func main() {
    handle, err = pcap.OpenLive(device,snaplen,promisc,timeout)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle,handle.LinkType())

    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        fmt.Println(packet)
    }
}
```

Comment: packets are not handled at application layer, so the answer is no

Comment: @Mox he is using the pcap library for low level access, he is no longer with the application layer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with go binding of netmap https://github.com/pragus/gonetmap